# Convert SmbFile to File how to?

Tags: java, file, smb, jcifs

I am trying to read a file from a server.
I am getting it with smb, but i need it to be a File[] array.

```
SmbFile dir = new SmbFile(url, auth);
for (SmbFile f : dir.listFiles()) {
    System.out.println(f.getName());
}
```

What I was thinking of doing a

```
SmbFile tmp = new SmbFile(url:"./");
tmp.createNewFile();
dir.copyTo(tmp);

File csvFile = new File("./");
```

Comment: As the newer `Path` also maintains a file system, maybe you rather want to use a `Path` instead of `File`. You can plugin Samba: https://gquintana.github.io/2017/09/02/Java-File-vs-Path.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SmbFile home = new SmbFile(ServerURL, authentication);

SmbFile[] files = home.listFiles((fileList, name) -> name.endsWith(".dat"));
```

Then just iterate through the files.